# Get remaining time and upload file speed - ajax jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
jQuery.ajax
({
    url: ajaxurl,
    type: "POST",
    xhr: function()
    {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener( 'progress', function( e )
        {
            if( e.lengthComputable )
            {
                // Append progress percentage.
                var loaded = e.loaded;
                var total = e.total;
                var progressValue = Math.round( ( loaded / total ) * 100 );

                // Bytes received.
                jQuery( '.recievedValue' ).html( '' );
                jQuery( '.recievedValue' ).append( formatFileSize( loaded ) + ' / ' );

                // Total bytes.
                jQuery( '.totalValue' ).html( '' );
                jQuery( '.totalValue' ).append( formatFileSize( total ) );

                // Percentage.
                progressElement.find( 'input' ).val( progressValue ).change();
            }
        }, false );
        return xhr;
    },
    success: function( data )
    {}
});
```

This is my ajax function. I can get loaded bytes, total bytes and percentage value. But I also need to get the remaining time and upload file speed in (kb/sec). is there any way i can get these two values. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A = 3'34s loaded bytes? 
B = 3'35s loaded bytes? 
C = B - A; 
C = C/1024 =>       C kb/s

Comment: Well, there is the Network Information API, but that is still in draft state, and only firefox has begun implementing it. But when you measure the elapsed time, you could do a (quite vague) approximation of the speed and remaining time …

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try something like this, it should get you in the right direction:

*Although finalized code would be cleaned-up/organized differently, I'll leave my answer recognizable to your original question so it's easier to relate to.*

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    type: "POST",
    xhr: function(){
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        var started_at = new Date();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener( 'progress', function( e ){
            if( e.lengthComputable ){
                // Append progress percentage.
                var loaded = e.loaded;
                var total = e.total;
                var progressValue = Math.round( ( loaded / total ) * 100 );

                // Bytes received.
                jQuery( '.receivedValue' ).html( '' );
                jQuery( '.receivedValue' ).append( formatFileSize( loaded ) + ' / ' );

                // Total bytes.
                jQuery( '.totalValue' ).html( '' );
                jQuery( '.totalValue' ).append( formatFileSize( total ) );

                // Time Remaining
                var seconds_elapsed =   ( new Date().getTime() - started_at.getTime() )/1000;
                var bytes_per_second =  seconds_elapsed ? loaded / seconds_elapsed : 0 ;
                var Kbytes_per_second = bytes_per_second / 1024 ;
                var remaining_bytes =   total - loaded;
                var seconds_remaining = seconds_elapsed ? remaining_bytes / bytes_per_second : 'calculating' ;
                jQuery( '.timeRemaining' ).html( '' );
                jQuery( '.timeRemaining' ).append( seconds_remaining );

                // Percentage.
                progressElement.find( 'input' ).val( progressValue ).change();
            }//if
        }, false );
        return xhr;
    },
    success: function( data ){}
});
```

---

### Supplemental (HTML & JavaScript)

Although the Original Question does not provide the accompanying HTML or `formatFileSize()` function, here's an assumed basic definition of each.

### HTML

```
<div id="progressElement">
  <div>
    <span class="receivedValue"></span>
    <span class="totalValue"></span>
  </div>
  <input name="percentage"/>
  <div class="timeRemaining"></div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var progressElement = document.getElementById('progressElement');

function formatFileSize(bytes){
    //  You can make this into something that intelligently outputs B,KB,MB,etc...
    return `${Math.round(bytes/1024)}KB`;
}
```

Comment: okay thanks i will try sometime later and respond back.

Comment: can i get upload speed from this var Kbytes_per_second? @FactoryAidan

Comment: Yes. But I would round it when you output it to the user with `Math.round(Kbytes_per_second)`

Comment: This is, by far, my favorite answer on the subject! 1 year later and you saved my butt! Thank you!

Comment: A Kb is 1024 bytes, not 1000 and formatFileSize is not defined!

Comment: Also, this is calculating the average speed not real-time speed of the upload.